# uniform.js form submission - needs double click in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, uniform

I am using the latest version of uniform.js with jquery.

In internet explorer when I try and submit the form it doesn't work the first time and have to click again

If I dont include the uniform library it works ok (ie one click on submit) but as soon as the library is added in IE a double click is required

here is an example

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/addArticlePopup/index.html

thanks